# Difference between Header Search Path and Library Search Path?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

This question is with context to iPhone -

What is the difference between `Header Search Paths` and `Library Search Paths` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Header search path is where the compiler will look for header files (i.e. the ".h" files you include from your class implementations.

Library search path is where the linker will look for compiled object files (or archive files containing those compiled object files) that are referenced from within the code being compiled and linked.

Comment: Thanks Tim. What is their relation with Other Linker Flags and also, when we add a framework/library from Projects-->Target-->Build Phases-->Link Binary With Libraries ... do we need to add Library Search Path for them?

Comment: Other linker flags are sometimes needed to have finer control over how the link process works. For example, when linking to certain external libraries I've had to add certain linker flags to make thinks work as needed. I wouldn't recommend you mess with these unless you come across instructions for something you are trying to accomplish that tell you what to put in there. As for frameworks added through Xcode, in many cases you won't have to add anything to the Library search path because it has reasonable defaults, but sometimes you might need to add additional directories to the library path

Answer (score 3):

**HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS vs LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS**

- `Header Search Paths(HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS)` - It is pre-compile time check that can throws `Module not found`. There are locations of the public headers(.h), simply tell Xcode where they are.
- `Library Search Path(LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS)` - It is compile time check that can throws `Library not found for`. There are locations of the libraries(executables), simply tell Xcode where they are to use it for linking. Sensitive to whitespace